# Exchange errors. How to verify configuration?

Tags: windows-server-2003, exchange, exchange-2003, windows-sbs-2003

They are having trouble with mail delivery (some get through, others don't).
What do you suggest I do to check the server configuration?

*Event Type: Error

Event Source: MSExchangeTransport

Event Category: SMTP Protocol

Event ID: 7004

Date: 1/18/2011

Time: 7:33:29 AM

User: N/A

Computer: SERVER

Description:

This is an SMTP protocol error log for virtual server ID 1, connection #621. The remote host "212.52.84.180", responded to the SMTP command "rcpt" with "550 #5.1.0 Address rejected brickkk@libero.it ". The full command sent was "RCPT TO: ". This will probably cause the connection to fail.*

---

*Event Type: Error

Event Source: MSExchangeTransport

Event Category: NDR

Event ID: 3018 
Date:  1/18/2011

Time:  9:49:37 AM

User:  N/A

Computer: SERVER

Description:

A non-delivery report with a status code of 5.4.0 was generated for recipient rfc822;denis.winckell@lalibero.it (Message-ID ).

Causes: This message indicates a DNS problem or an IP address configuration problem

Solution: Check the DNS using nslookup or dnsq. Verify the IP address is in IPv4 literal format.

Data:

0000: ef 02 04 c0               ï..À*

Answer (score 2):

It seems pretty clear to me:

> The remote host "212.52.84.180", responded to the SMTP command "rcpt" with "550 #5.1.0 Address rejected brickkk@libero.it

The recipient address was rejected. Have you verified that this is a valid email address?

> This message indicates a DNS problem or an IP address configuration problem

Have you verfied that the remote domain exists and that the MX or A record for the remote domain can be resolved?

Comment: The problem is no one in this company (15 people) sends emails to anyone in Italy and our logs are full of these types of errors. There are a lot of emails to Italy... I guess someone is using our server to relay spam. How can I check and block this or find the source?

Comment: None of that was apparent from your question. My guess is that one of your users has a computer that's infected with malware.

Comment: Sorry. I posted a much longer/detailed question a few weeks ago (same issue) and earned the Tumbleweed Badge, so I thought I'd try the short and sweet version this time.

What's the best method to track it down? I had scanned and updated most of the computers (there were infections), but this persists weeks later. I've done a lot of troubleshooting, but can't seem to nail it down.

Comment: What's the best way to get help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Start with the following site:
http://www.mxtoolbox.com/

It will allow you to validate if your server is on any spam lists.